# Blocked google map, unable to pan and zoom, JS error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am unable to pan and zoom on this very basic map, based on the Google maps Api code sample.

The map is **[here](http://bit.ly/1G9oBs1)**.

As you can see in console, I get this first error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribution' of undefined
```

And after I go on the map with the mouse, a lot of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetX' of undefined
```

I am able to make zoom and pan working by including **[this library](http://http//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.19&sensor=true)**.

But in this case I get the controls wrong like **[this capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/250uhx1cpqnrbio/20150604-18_49_42-000170.png?dl=0)**.

Comment: It's obviously a conflict with mootools

Comment: Thanks fixed the mootool conflict